# Adding single or multiple className on styledComponent not showing the style on the server

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

As mentioned in the question title I am trying to style, with ClassName, a component by adding a class to my StyledComponents but despite I believe I added the classes in the right way the style wont show, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. any clues? I am

talking about the classes:

1. "sunday" in the styledComponent **Date**
2. "active-month" in the styledComponent **Date**
3. "active" in the styledComponent **text**

This is the code:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please parse the actual code, not images.

Comment: Yes, please do update your question to include properly formatted and readable code snippets. Images are more difficult to read, can't be copied from, and they aren't searchable.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to use the ampersand (`&`) to refer back to the parent components, `Date` and `Text`.

[Pseudoelements, pseudoselectors, and nesting](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting)

> The ampersand (`&`) can be used to refer back to the main component.

> If you put selectors in without the ampersand, they will refer to
> children of the component.

Example:

```
const Date = styled.div`
  ....
  &.sunday {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }
  &.active-month {
    transition: color 0.3s ease-in;
    color: black;
  }
`;
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Drew, I figured it out too:) do you know how I can mark this question as solved?